# How can I prevent a contenteditable <p> from pushing down its sibling elements when wrapping?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="entry-title-bar">
      <p id="1date" class="entry-date" onkeyup="updateentry(1)" contenteditable="">Date</p><span class="entry-date-dot">•</span>
      <p id="1title" class="entry-title" onkeyup="updateentry(1)" contenteditable="">Title</p>
      <div class="entry-buttons-container">
        <i class="fa fa-trash line-remove-entry presentation-hide" onclick="remove(1)" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-h entry-menu-button presentation-hide" onclick="openSettingsDialog('1')" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div><hr style="margin-top: 0;">
        <p id="1desc" class="entry-description" onkeyup="updateentry(1)" contenteditable="">Description</p>
  </div>
```

Currently, if you type in `entry-title` enough that it wraps, it goes from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

What I want is for it to not push the buttons in `entry-buttons-container` down, and for them to stay where they begin.

How can I resolve this with CSS?

Comment: did you try white-space:nowrap ?

Comment: and combine it with: 
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
to have a nice (...) effect when it overflows.